# Python - How do you assign a variable to a table displayed on seperate lines

Tags: python, list

Sorry for the horrible title. But what im trying to do is here

```
import pyperclip
y = []
for x in range(1,158):
    y.append("- " + str(x))


pyperclip.copy(y)
```

What I get is the table, but when its copied to the clipboard its pasted left to right
I want the elements of a list to be pasted downward

so instead of

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

I'd get

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Does adding a newline after each element not work?

Comment: Actually, this is a good title.  It tells me what you want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need newline characters, `'\n'`, in your string. Try this

```
import pyperclip
y = []
for x in range(1,158):
    y.append("- " + str(x) + '\n')

pyperclip.copy(y)
```

A more pythonic way would be

```
import pyperclip
y = '\n'.join('- ' + str(x) for x in range(1, 158))
pyperclip.copy(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
y.append("- " + str(x))
```

to:

```
y.append("- " + str(x) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new line character:

```
y = []
for x in range(1,158):
    y.append("- " + str(x) + "\n")
```